# How to pass parameters to a procedure in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16

I have a C program that calls a two procedures from my assembly file, the procedures are defined like this `extern int myfunc(int a,int b)` and `myfunc2(int c,int d)` ,now after `myfunc` call in C, i can access the parameters in assembly like this: **b** is at `[BP+6]` and **a** is at `[BP+4]` this is in the SMALL MODEL.
Now i want to call `myfunc2(int c,int d)` but from my assembly file while i'm in my `myfunc`.
How do i set up the stack for `myfunc2` and pass it parameters?
And will it mess up the current stack for `myfunc` ,if yes how do i deal with that?
**MY Assembly file:**

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
.CODE
PUBLIC _myfunc
PUBLIC _myfunc2
_myfunc PROC NEAR
.386
PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP
;here i need to do myfun2(1,2)
POP BP
RET
_myfunc ENDP

_myfunc2 PROC NEAR
.386
PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP
MOV DX,[BP+6];get d
MOV AX,[BP+4];get c
ADD AX,DX;add them up
;the return value will be in AX
POP BP
RET
_myfunc2 ENDP

END
```

**MY C file:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

extern int myfunc(int a,int b);
extern int myfunc2(int c,int d);
int main()
{
    int res;
    res=myfunc(int a,int b);
}
```

Comment: Don;t describe your code....show it.

Comment: Show your attempt so far, please.

Comment: Write a dummy  `myfunc` function in C with a call to `myfunc2`, and look at the assembly code generated by the C compiler.

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set up the stack by pushing values onto it. The beauty of the stack mechanism is that passing parameters to another function will *not* mess up the stack of the current function, provided that you do not do anything terribly wrong.

There is no simple answer to your question because a lot depends on the ABI (Application Binary Interface) in use, on the *calling convention* of your function, (is it `cdecl`?), etc.

The safest way to go about it is to have your C compiler generate assembly output of your C code, and then do as it does.  But in general, it will look like this:

```
push ax          ; pass int c parameter (assuming int is 16-bit)
push dx          ; pass int d parameter (assuming int is 16-bit)
call _myfunc2    ; invoke the function
add sp, 4        ; clean up stack (assuming cdecl calling convention)
```

The above assumes that an `int` is 16-bit, which is I think reasonable when I hear you speaking of `MODEL SMALL`.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why did you add 4 to sp ?

Comment: Never mind i understand now its the same as doing POP for ax and dx after the call, thank you.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Because there truly isn't really a simple answer, the best way to go about this is with the gnu debugger, or the docs, but you'll end up in gdb anyway. One way is to write the programs in C, disassemble them, and see for yourself what the calling conventions are. You could use the stack, you could just as easily use registers to pass these simple values as 64-bit typically does and 32-bit syscalls do.

```
//testc.c
int func2(int c, int d)
{
    return c-d;
}


int func(int a, int b)
{
    a+=2;
    b++;
    func2(a,b); 

}


//cfile.c

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

extern int func(int a,int b);
extern int func2(int c,int d);
int main()
{
    int res;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 3;
    res=func(b, c);
}
```

Compiling

```
$ gcc -m32 -g -c testc.c
unroot@flerb:~/stacko$ gcc -m32 -g cfile.o testc.o -o a.out
unroot@flerb:~/stacko$ ./a.out
unroot@flerb:~/stacko$ echo $?
0
```

In gdb

```
$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) set listsize 50
(gdb) list 0
1   #include <stdio.h> 
2   #include <stdlib.h> 
3   
4   extern int func(int a,int b);
5   extern int func2(int c,int d);
6   int main()
7   {
8       int res;
9       int b = 4;
10      int c = 3;
11      res=func(b, c);
12  }


(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x57c: file cfile.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/unroot/stacko/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at cfile.c:9
9       int b = 4;
```

Looking at the contents of the stack when we're breaked at main

```
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd290: 0x00000001  0xffffd354  0xffffd35c  0x56555611
0xffffd2a0: 0xffffd2c0  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276
0xffffd2b0: 0x00000001  0xf7fad000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276
0xffffd2c0: 0x00000001  0xffffd354  0xffffd35c  0x00000000
0xffffd2d0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7fad000  0xf7ffdc04
```

Just to have a quick look at the contents before parameters are pushed on

```
(gdb) x/20x $esp-0x10
0xffffd280: 0x00000003  0x56557000  0x00000001  0x56555577
0xffffd290: 0x00000001  0xffffd354  0xffffd35c  0x56555611
0xffffd2a0: 0xffffd2c0  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276
0xffffd2b0: 0x00000001  0xf7fad000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276
0xffffd2c0: 0x00000001  0xffffd354  0xffffd35c  0x00000000
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x56555560 <+0>: lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x56555564 <+4>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x56555567 <+7>: push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x5655556a <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x5655556b <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x5655556d <+13>:    push   ebx
   0x5655556e <+14>:    push   ecx
   0x5655556f <+15>:    sub    esp,0x10
   0x56555572 <+18>:    call   0x565555af <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x56555577 <+23>:    add    eax,0x1a89
=> 0x5655557c <+28>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x4
   0x56555583 <+35>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],0x3
   0x5655558a <+42>:    sub    esp,0x8
   0x5655558d <+45>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10]
   0x56555590 <+48>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
   0x56555593 <+51>:    mov    ebx,eax
   0x56555595 <+53>:    call   0x565555c8 <func>
   0x5655559a <+58>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x5655559d <+61>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],eax
   0x565555a0 <+64>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x565555a5 <+69>:    lea    esp,[ebp-0x8]
   0x565555a8 <+72>:    pop    ecx
   0x565555a9 <+73>:    pop    ebx
   0x565555aa <+74>:    pop    ebp
   0x565555ab <+75>:    lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
   0x565555ae <+78>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break *0x56555595 
Breakpoint 2 at 0x56555595: file cfile.c, line 11.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
```

Look at contents of stack now, c=3 was pushed on, and then b=4 (notice I'm only writing this like this for ease, the values pushed on are purely values and have no connection with the variables that represent them once they are on the stack)

```
Breakpoint 2, 0x56555595 in main () at cfile.c:11
11      res=func(b, c);
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd280: 0x00000004  0x00000003  0x00000001  0x56555577
0xffffd290: 0x00000001  0xffffd354  0x00000003  0x00000004
0xffffd2a0: 0xffffd2c0  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276
0xffffd2b0: 0x00000001  0xf7fad000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276
0xffffd2c0: 0x00000001  0xffffd354  0xffffd35c  0x00000000
(gdb)
```

So the parameters to the func call were pushed in reverse order, push 3 then push 4, evident because the stack is growing downwards to smaller addresses. When the called function accesses these parameters sometimes it will pop 4 off first and then 3 into separate registers using esp, or, as shown under the disassembly below, the called function can access them by pointers from ebp.

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x56555560 <+0>: lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x56555564 <+4>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x56555567 <+7>: push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x5655556a <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x5655556b <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x5655556d <+13>:    push   ebx
   0x5655556e <+14>:    push   ecx
   0x5655556f <+15>:    sub    esp,0x10
   0x56555572 <+18>:    call   0x565555af <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x56555577 <+23>:    add    eax,0x1a89
   0x5655557c <+28>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x4
   0x56555583 <+35>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],0x3
   0x5655558a <+42>:    sub    esp,0x8
   0x5655558d <+45>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10]
   0x56555590 <+48>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
   0x56555593 <+51>:    mov    ebx,eax
=> 0x56555595 <+53>:    call   0x565555c8 <func>
   0x5655559a <+58>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x5655559d <+61>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],eax
   0x565555a0 <+64>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x565555a5 <+69>:    lea    esp,[ebp-0x8]
   0x565555a8 <+72>:    pop    ecx
   0x565555a9 <+73>:    pop    ebx
   0x565555aa <+74>:    pop    ebp
   0x565555ab <+75>:    lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
   0x565555ae <+78>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Stepping in to func

```
(gdb) stepi
func (a=4, b=3) at testc.c:9
9   {
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function func:
=> 0x565555c8 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x565555c9 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x565555cb <+3>: call   0x565555af <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x565555d0 <+8>: add    eax,0x1a30
   0x565555d5 <+13>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x2
   0x565555d9 <+17>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc],0x1
   0x565555dd <+21>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x565555e0 <+24>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x565555e3 <+27>:    call   0x565555b3 <func2>
   0x565555e8 <+32>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x565555eb <+35>:    nop
   0x565555ec <+36>:    leave  
   0x565555ed <+37>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

The C call function pushed the return value onto the stack without any obvious hint that it was going to do that, but it's there taking up space

```
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd27c: 0x5655559a  0x00000004  0x00000003  0x00000001
0xffffd28c: 0x56555577  0x00000001  0xffffd354  0x00000003
0xffffd29c: 0x00000004  0xffffd2c0  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xffffd2ac: 0xf7e12276  0x00000001  0xf7fad000  0x00000000
0xffffd2bc: 0xf7e12276  0x00000001  0xffffd354  0xffffd35c
```

Then we step forward into the substance of func, where an offset from ebp is used to add 2 to a (the second function pushed onto the stack, which is therefore closer to ebp on the stack) and to add 1 to b which was pushed just before it

```
(gdb) step
10      a+=2;

(gdb) print/x $ebp
$1 = 0xffffd278

(gdb) x/20x $ebp
0xffffd278: 0xffffd2a8  0x5655559a  0x00000004  0x00000003
0xffffd288: 0x00000001  0x56555577  0x00000001  0xffffd354
0xffffd298: 0x00000003  0x00000004  0xffffd2c0  0x00000000
0xffffd2a8: 0x00000000  0xf7e12276  0x00000001  0xf7fad000
0xffffd2b8: 0x00000000  0xf7e12276  0x00000001  0xffffd354


(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function func:
   0x565555c8 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x565555c9 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x565555cb <+3>: call   0x565555af <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x565555d0 <+8>: add    eax,0x1a30
=> 0x565555d5 <+13>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x2      //a+=2
   0x565555d9 <+17>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc],0x1      //b++
   0x565555dd <+21>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]      //push b
   0x565555e0 <+24>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]      //push a
   0x565555e3 <+27>:    call   0x565555b3 <func2>
   0x565555e8 <+32>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x565555eb <+35>:    nop
   0x565555ec <+36>:    leave  
   0x565555ed <+37>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Breaking at the call and checking the stack again

```
(gdb) break *0x565555e3
Breakpoint 3 at 0x565555e3: file testc.c, line 12.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, 0x565555e3 in func (a=6, b=4) at testc.c:12
12      func2(a,b); 
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function func:
   0x565555c8 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x565555c9 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x565555cb <+3>: call   0x565555af <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x565555d0 <+8>: add    eax,0x1a30
   0x565555d5 <+13>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x2
   0x565555d9 <+17>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc],0x1
   0x565555dd <+21>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x565555e0 <+24>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
=> 0x565555e3 <+27>:    call   0x565555b3 <func2>
   0x565555e8 <+32>:    add    esp,0x8
   0x565555eb <+35>:    nop
   0x565555ec <+36>:    leave  
   0x565555ed <+37>:    ret   

(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd270: 0x00000006  0x00000004  0xffffd2a8  0x5655559a
0xffffd280: 0x00000006  0x00000004  0x00000001  0x56555577
0xffffd290: 0x00000001  0xffffd354  0x00000003  0x00000004
0xffffd2a0: 0xffffd2c0  0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276
0xffffd2b0: 0x00000001  0xf7fad000  0x00000000  0xf7e12276

Again our variables have been pushed on the stack, again in reverse order, as always, but you could control this too in assembly if you feel like being difficult.

(gdb) stepi
func2 (c=6, d=4) at testc.c:3
3   {
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function func2:
=> 0x565555b3 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x565555b4 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x565555b6 <+3>: call   0x565555af <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x565555bb <+8>: add    eax,0x1a45
   0x565555c0 <+13>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x565555c3 <+16>:    sub    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x565555c6 <+19>:    pop    ebp
   0x565555c7 <+20>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.

Again the call pushes the return address onto the stack before transfering control to the called function. 
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd26c: 0x565555e8  0x00000006  0x00000004  0xffffd2a8
0xffffd27c: 0x5655559a  0x00000006  0x00000004  0x00000001
0xffffd28c: 0x56555577  0x00000001  0xffffd354  0x00000003
0xffffd29c: 0x00000004  0xffffd2c0  0x00000000  0x00000000
0xffffd2ac: 0xf7e12276  0x00000001  0xf7fad000  0x00000000
```

Continuing and breaking at the substance of the called function.

```
(gdb) break *0x565555c0
Breakpoint 4 at 0x565555c0: file testc.c, line 4.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.


Breakpoint 4, func2 (c=6, d=4) at testc.c:4
4       return c-d;


(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function func2:
   0x565555b3 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x565555b4 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x565555b6 <+3>: call   0x565555af <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x565555bb <+8>: add    eax,0x1a45
=> 0x565555c0 <+13>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x565555c3 <+16>:    sub    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x565555c6 <+19>:    pop    ebp
   0x565555c7 <+20>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Examining the stack at the substance of func2, where the variables are accessed and the subtraction happens:

```
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd268: 0xffffd278  0x565555e8  0x00000006  0x00000004
0xffffd278: 0xffffd2a8  0x5655559a  0x00000006  0x00000004
0xffffd288: 0x00000001  0x56555577  0x00000001  0xffffd354
0xffffd298: 0x00000003  0x00000004  0xffffd2c0  0x00000000
0xffffd2a8: 0x00000000  0xf7e12276  0x00000001  0xf7fad000
(gdb) x/20x $ebp
0xffffd268: 0xffffd278  0x565555e8  0x00000006  0x00000004
0xffffd278: 0xffffd2a8  0x5655559a  0x00000006  0x00000004
0xffffd288: 0x00000001  0x56555577  0x00000001  0xffffd354
0xffffd298: 0x00000003  0x00000004  0xffffd2c0  0x00000000
0xffffd2a8: 0x00000000  0xf7e12276  0x00000001  0xf7fad000
```

So here [ebp+0x8] = 6 and [ebp+0xc] = 4 and the values are modified with the subtract instruction in the eax register, returning the result into the eax register.

Default convention for C is to let the caller push the return address prior to transferring control to the callee, and have the callee adjust the stack and base pointers, but you can do whatever you want when you're calling your own function and returning to your own function. Here I used C programs to illustrate what C does, but if you're using C to call an assembly program which calls another assembly program then you have explicit control of the base pointer between those assembly programs if you want it. You can chose to adjust them manually and jmp to your second function call, which will circumvent the automatic call procedure of pushing the return address and setting up the stack, not entirely useful; or the assembly call instruction will use the same procedure to initialize the called function and you can expect the offsets to be the same as in C functions.

[Good link on x86 Call conventions including cdecl and stdcall](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html)
and
[A handy syscall reference showing use of registers for function calls](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/)

This is a simple example of using registers to pass variables in 32 bit, no stack necessary. 
    //testasm32.asm
    section .text
        global _start

```
_start:
    mov ecx, hello1
    call print_string
    mov ecx, hello2
    call print_string

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

print_string:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, 6
    int 0x80
    ret

section .data
    hello1 db "Hello1"
    hello2 db "Hello2"

$ nasm -f elf32 testasm32.asm
unroot@flerb:~/LearningLinuxBinaryAnalysis_Code$ ld -m elf_i386 -o testasm32 testasm32.o
unroot@flerb:~/LearningLinuxBinaryAnalysis_Code$ ./testasm32
Hello1Hello2

$ echo $?
1
```

Interestingly ebx holds the error code for the exit syscall, so it returns 1 because ebx was set to 1 in the print_string command and was not cleared.